# Memory management when using PageViewer and LayoutPagerAdapter

Tags: c#, android, memory, xamarin, android-viewpager

I have a welcoming activity that is using **ViewPager** and custom **LayoutPagerAdapter**. The thing is that layouts contain quite large images and keeping them in the memory is not what is desirable.

That's why I am **recycling** them when **OnDestroyItem** is called.

When I do the recycling though it breaks the app. Basically shuts down the VM.

Here is the code for the **LayoutPagerAdapter**.

```
public class LayoutPagerAdapter : PagerAdapter
    {
        Context m_context;
        readonly int[] m_slideLayoutResourceIds;

        public LayoutPagerAdapter(Context context, int[] slideLayoutResourceIds)
        {
            m_context = context;
            m_slideLayoutResourceIds = slideLayoutResourceIds;
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
        {
            var inflater = LayoutInflater.From(m_context);

            var view = inflater.Inflate(m_slideLayoutResourceIds[position], container, false);

            container.AddView(view);

            return view;
        }

        public override void DestroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Java.Lang.Object objectValue)
        {
            var bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)((View)objectValue).FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.welcomeBackgroundImage).Drawable;
            bitmapDrawable.Bitmap.Recycle();

            container.RemoveView((View)objectValue);
        }

        #region implemented abstract members of PagerAdapter

        public override bool IsViewFromObject(View view, Java.Lang.Object objectValue)
        {
            return view == objectValue;
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return m_slideLayoutResourceIds.Length;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

This line proceeds fine but breaks the app by not allowing me to scroll back and shuts down the VM for some reason.

```
var bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)((View)objectValue).FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.welcomeBackgroundImage).Drawable;
                bitmapDrawable.Bitmap.Recycle();
```

Here is the activity code for completeness.

```
[Activity(MainLauncher = true, Label = "")]         
    public class WelcomeActivity : Activity
    {
        ViewPager m_welcomeViewPager;
        LayoutPagerAdapter m_layoutPagerAdapter;
        TextView m_welcomeSkipButton;
        CirclePageIndicator m_circlePageIndicator;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Welcome);

            m_circlePageIndicator = FindViewById<CirclePageIndicator>(Resource.Id.welcomeCirclePageIndicator);
            m_welcomeSkipButton = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.welcomeSkipButton);
            m_welcomeViewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.welcomeViewPager);

            m_layoutPagerAdapter = new LayoutPagerAdapter(this, 
                new []
                { 
                    Resource.Layout.welcome_slide_1, 
                    Resource.Layout.welcome_slide_2,
                    Resource.Layout.welcome_slide_3,
                    Resource.Layout.welcome_slide_4,
                    Resource.Layout.welcome_slide_5,
                    Resource.Layout.welcome_slide_6
                });

            m_welcomeViewPager.Adapter = m_layoutPagerAdapter;
            m_circlePageIndicator.SetViewPager(m_welcomeViewPager);
            m_circlePageIndicator.SetCurrentItem(0);
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();

            m_welcomeSkipButton.Click += WelcomeSkipButtonClick;
        }

        void WelcomeSkipButtonClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO
        }

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();

            m_welcomeSkipButton.Click -= WelcomeSkipButtonClick;
        }

        protected override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();

            if (m_circlePageIndicator != null)
            {
                m_circlePageIndicator.Dispose();
                m_circlePageIndicator = null;
            }

            if (m_layoutPagerAdapter != null)
            {
                m_layoutPagerAdapter.Dispose();
                m_layoutPagerAdapter = null;
            }

            if (m_welcomeSkipButton != null)
            {
                m_welcomeSkipButton.Dispose();
                m_welcomeSkipButton = null;
            }

            if (m_welcomeViewPager != null)
            {
                m_welcomeViewPager.Dispose();
                m_welcomeViewPager = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the application output when scrolling through the layouts and then the VM shutdown.

```
[dalvikvm-heap] Grow heap (frag case) to 24.469MB for 2810896-byte allocation
[dalvikvm-heap] Grow heap (frag case) to 30.500MB for 6324496-byte allocation
[dalvikvm-heap] Grow heap (frag case) to 24.487MB for 2810896-byte allocation
[dalvikvm-heap] Grow heap (frag case) to 30.517MB for 6324496-byte allocation
[dalvikvm-heap] Grow heap (frag case) to 25.001MB for 2810896-byte allocation
[dalvikvm-heap] Grow heap (frag case) to 31.032MB for 6324496-byte allocation
[AndroidRuntime] Shutting down VM
```

I would expect the app to simply re-instantiate the layouts when I try to scroll back. Why would the recycling be preventing it?

Comment: Have you tried reading through http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/general/load_large_bitmaps_efficiently/ also you might want to look into using WeakReferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that recycling should be only used when you are sure you won't want to display the images anymore. In my case this wasn't true. I did want to display the layout again.

I removed the line and I resized down the images heavily. In my case from 250 kb image to 75 kb which basically solved all my memory issues.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to checkout this article about Bitmap memory management (https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html). If you're targeting Android 3.0 or greater, there's a different paradigm used for recycling bitmaps instead of manually calling `recycle()`.

Since you are using large bitmaps, I'd highly recommend using a library like `Picasso` or `Glide` to load in the images. A lot of the boilerplate work has been taken care of for you, and you can easily cache images at a high level if necessary. One more possible tip, if the image is not a photo, or you don't need the alpha channel/higher color depth, try using `RGB565` vs `ARGB8888` for less memory usage.